# how to send mail using CRUD in YII2

Tags: email, yii2

[image]

I have CRUD of task distributor. and a dropdown of task created using select 2 widget. 
to send mail I have written code in **controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
 $model =new TaskDistributor();
 $modelcompany = new Companies();

 $companies = Companies::find()->all();
 $companiesList = ArrayHelper::map($companies,'id','name');

 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
  {
   $model->task = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'task');       
       if( $model->task )
       {
        $value = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom(['pharmadarshu@gmail.com' => 'task_distributor'])
        ->setTo($model->sendto)
        ->setSubject($model->subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($model->comment)
        ->attach($model->task)
        ->send();
       }
       else{
        $value = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom(['pharmadarshu@gmail.com' => 'task_distributor'])
        ->setTo($model->sendto)
        ->setSubject($model->subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($model->task)
        ->send();
       }
       $model->save();
      // print_r($model->getErrors()); die(); it gives task can not be blank
       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->no]);
      }else{
return $this->render('create',[
'model' => $model ,
'companiesList' => $companiesList,
]);
}
}
```

when I run the code.It sends the mail. but task field goes empty in the mail and gives error=> 400 bad request.
 then how to get value of select2 dropdown selected value in mail?

Comment: Check `$model->task` value, after post.

Comment: it is blank ..why so ?? I have selected from dropdown then why it is blank

Comment: check  `Yii::$app->request->post()` also. Add your model and form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function actionCreate()
{
 $model =new TaskDistributor();
 $modelcompany = new Companies();

 $companies = Companies::find()->all();
 $companiesList = ArrayHelper::map($companies,'id','name');

 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
  {

        $value = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom(['pharmadarshu@gmail.com' => 'task_distributor'])
        ->setTo($model->sendto)
        ->setSubject($model->subject)
        ->setHtmlBody($model->task)
        ->send();

       $model->save();

       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->no]);
      }else{
    return $this->render('create',[
    'model' => $model ,
    'companiesList' => $companiesList,
]);
}
}
```

Comment: "task" is not attachment.. I want to select it from dropdown list

Comment: your problem is don't get $model->task ?

Comment: thanks... it was my mistake... just removed... $model->task = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'task'); ...and it works fine

Comment: what if i want to send one more field ->setHtmlBody($model->comment)

Comment: That you want to combine commaent and task in html body .?

Comment: @Goli  see comment above

Comment: yes.. and tried this... ->setHtmlBody($model->comment.$model->task)...but error " array to string conversion"

Comment: You have to change that please make an question and mention me to completely answer you @Goli

Comment: will try first then post a que